# Where to save data coming from server in android application?

Tags: android, social-networking

I am creating an social networking kind of application in Android.In which I am getting lots of data from server in XML format.

Currently I am saving that data in static List & Maps,so I can use this data wherever I want.But I don't know whether it is a good way of saving data or not.

Actually I want to save data for a session only and that should be accessible from any where in my app.And on ending session I want to clear all data.

So what is the right way to save the data and use it.

Answer (score 1):

i think u need to **save data on server** itself.
bcoz saving in database is not proper way,once user uninstalls the app all the data gets lost.
Moreover once user sigin in other device u will not get refreshed data.

Comment: Thanks for response Richa but I want to save data temporarily so I can use it for a session only.So next time I will again parse data and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working facebook or google+ or some existing social networking service, you should be fine with static objects.  Also assuming only one person can be logged in a time, this won't be a problem.  Just make sure you clear your static objects and refresh from the server often enough that your local copy of the data doesn't get stale.

Comment: I am already working the way you suggest.But I get lots of data in xml (eg list of my all contacts,messages etc) ,so my doubt is this is it ok to save these much data in static lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse xml data and using namevaluepairs you can send all the data to server side pages and on server side you can retrieve that data and store that to your sql database.or simply use sqlite in app itself..

Comment: Some time I get so much complex xml's data like it contains so many subtags so I find it very complicated to save in namevauepairs.any suggestion on this.